# SharePoint 2010 use third-party editor

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-2010

Sp 2010 content editor is better than 2007 but it's lacking lots of functionality.

Is it possible to "substitute" standard rich text editor with something like FCK or Telerik editor?

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Browser based rich text editors, including the one used by SharePoint, work by using javascript to modify the standard textbox that the server renders in the form.

All you need to do is make sure that your script runs instead of the default sharepoint script, which is easy enough to do by declaring your own function with the same name used by the default editor.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it is very much possible. Infact, telerik has whole set of controls specifically designed for Sharepoint 2010 and they integrate seamlessly with sharepoint.

As indicated below, it should be easy to integrate Telerik's RadEditor for SharePoint into existing SharePoint sites:

http://sharepoint.telerik.com/aspnet-ajax/Pages/RadEditor-for-SharePoint.aspx

Basically, it comes with these:

1. A WebPart that you can put on the new pages. You use Telerik's RadEditor for SharePoint Web part instead of Content Editor Web Part.
2. **[I GUESS THIS IS WHAT YOU ARE LOOKING FOR]** Looking at Telerik's documentation below, it sounds like once you install the Telerik RadEditor for SharePoint on the server, you just need to activate SITE or WEB level feature to replace the existing editor with Telerik's editor.

http://sharepoint.telerik.com/aspnet-ajax/web-parts/Pages/Content-Editor-Web-Part-using-RadEditor.aspx

Comment: So, how would I go about it? Note:i'm not asking how to add FCK editor to Sharepoint but how to REPLACE standard editor with something else

Comment: Sorry, I thought you would have done it already. I did little more research on this and updated my answer. Please review it.